# Unable to extract value from json array column in BigQUERY

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

I have a table column in `BigQuery` with `JSON` array format with a row like *`{"role":"SuperAdmin","_id":"abcd","userId":"efgh"}`*. This column schema in BigQuery is REPEATED mode. My goal is to extract the `userId` value for all the rows in that column.

I have tried using `JSON` functions like `json_value` and `json_extract`:

```
select  json_value(column_name, '$.users.userId') as userId,  from table_name
```

but get the following error :

```
No matching signature for function JSON_VALUE for argument types: ARRAY<STRING>, STRING. Supported signature: JSON_VALUE(STRING, [STRING]) at [2:3]
```

Please how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is repeated you will need to unnest it first.

Given the following example:

```
with sample_data as (
    select ['{"role":"SuperAdmin","_id":"abcd","userId":"efgh"}','{"role":"SuperAdmin","_id":"abcd","userId":"efgh"}','{"role":"SuperAdmin","_id":"abcd","userId":"efgh"}'] as users
)

select json_value(user, '$.userId') as userId
from sample_data , UNNEST(users) user
```

The return is:

[image]

Comment: Terrific, if it helped please consider marking correct and up voting.